# Is there a way to just display HTML and not run it?

Tags: php, html

I need this to create a 'code' area on my forum like here on Stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass your code through the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://it.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function before sending it as output.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can use 'strip_tags', too, but with this method?

Comment: Nevermind! I got it! I just used htmlspecialchars_decode, then I used strip_tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, you can indeed use the htmlspecialchars() function. Your question didn't state "with PHP" though. At the bare minimum, you will need to use an entity for <, which is &lt;. Ampersands should always be entities as well, since an & marks the start of an entity.

Finally, you will want to mark it up properly. This means using <pre><code> ... </code></pre>. <pre> for preformatted text, and <code> for a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use tags `<pre>  (your contente here) </pre>`

Comment: html-tags inside of pre are still interpreted. He needs to run htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars ( $yourcode ) . '</pre>';
```